# How much incentives is too much?

Tags: research, feedback, interview, incentives

While planing the research for a conference paper, a question remains present to us. The study involves three simple steps: (1) initial participatory interview; (2) participants interaction with a home device during a couple of weeks; and (3) a final interview to collect feedback.

For this type of studies, companies are paying an average amount of money to recruit and motivate participants. However, there is an information lack regarding what should be the number of incentives, as well as the corresponding amount, for study purposes. So, our questions are as follows.

List of questions to be answered:

- How many incentives are too much?
- Is there any *State-Of-The-Art* to follow the above concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Nielson Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/) is an excellent resource on a wide variety of UX topics. In this case they've actually conducted a study on how people incentivize recruits, among many other things.

They found that you'll typically want to pay about $60 / hour for external participants. To read more detailed findings, start at the section titled [Determining the Appropriate Incentives](https://media.nngroup.com/media/reports/free/How_To_Recruit_Participants_for_Usability_Studies.pdf). It begins on page 31.